# How routing with react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I installed react-router-dom and use this code for routing, But i have error :

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';


class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <h1>Home</h1>
        );
    }
}

class About extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <h1>About</h1>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
        <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
    </Switch>,
    document.getElementById('main')
);
```

What's the right way for routing in reactjs ?

tnx

Comment: What is the error? Can you post the error?

Comment: @ElumalaiKaliyaperumal : You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>

Comment: Wrap `BrowserRouter` around your `Switch` routes. That might be the problem. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @ElumalaiKaliyaperumal thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 3):

Wrap `BrowserRouter` around your `Switch` like below,

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path='/about' component={About} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Here is the working code demo in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rm6033969p).

Answer (score 2):

1. You didn't import `BrowserRouter`
2. You should wrap your `<Switch>` arround `<BrowserRouter>` tag
3. Better use a component than trying to render a `<Switch>` element

You may find anything your looking for on this link :

> https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy

Also i made a quick pen : [https://codepen.io/FabienGreard/pen/KZgwKO?editors=1010](https://codepen.io/FabienGreard/pen/KZgwKO)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**Kay Concepts**
**`<BrowserRouter>`** is needed because

- Each router creates a history object, which it uses to keep track of the current location and re-render the website whenever that changes
- A React Router component that does not have a router as one of its ancestors will fail to work.
- Router components only expect to receive a single child element. To work within this limitation, it is useful to create an  component that renders the rest of your application.

**`<Route>`**

- The  component is the main building block of React Router. Anywhere that you want to only render content based on the location’s pathname, you should use a  element.

**`<Path>`**

- When the current location’s pathname is matched by the path, the route will render a React element.

**`<Switch>`**

- You can use the component to group s.
- The  will iterate over its children elements (the routes) and only render the first one that matches the current pathname.

I think you should create different component for Routes.

I'll just explain general project structure here

You can create  component to hold `<Header>` and `<MainContent>`
As `<Header>` will be same througout the application and it will not change if path changes. You can include routes in `<MainContent>` which will be updated if path changes.

**MainContent.js**

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

  const MainContent = () => (
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
        <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
      </Switch>
    </main>
 )

 export default MainContent;
```

**Layout.js**

```
class Layout extends Component {
     render() {
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <Header />
                <MainContent />
            </div>
        );
}
```

Now you can use `<BrowserRouter>`to wrap your `<Layout>`  in App.js . or you can use it in `<MainContent>` as well

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
class App extends  Component {
render() {

return(
<BrowserRoter>
  <Layout />
 </BrowserRouter>
);
}
}
```